# jquery wont take different data except from one in first row

Tags: jquery, button, cart

I have an issue with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). I have one `<table>` dynamically.

```
foreach ($_cards as $_card){

    $tabOdd = "";

    $statusInd = "";

    $counter++;

    if ($counter % 2 != 0){

        $tabOdd = "style='background-color:#eee'";

    }


    echo '<tr id="r'.$counter.'">';

    echo '<td '.$tabOdd.'>'.$counter.'</td>
        <input type="hidden" class="ajdi" name="id" value="'.$_card["id"].'">
        <td '.$tabOdd.'>'.$_card["title"].'</td>
        <input type="hidden" id="title" name="title" data-id="'.$_card["id"].'" value="'.$_card["title"].'">
        <td '.$tabOdd.' onclick="tdOption(this);">

            <span class="fSpan">'.$_card["description"].'</span>

            <input type="text" class="fSel" data-field="description" data-id="'.$_card["id"].'" style="width:150px;display:none">
             <input type="hidden" id="description" name="title" data-id="'.$_card["id"].'" value="'.$_card["description"].'">
        </td>

        <td '.$tabOdd.' onclick="tdOption(this);">

            <!--<span class="fSpan">'.$_card["quantity"].'</span>-->
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity">

            <input type="text"  data-field="quantity" data-id="'.$_card["id"].'" style="width:150px;display:none">

        </td>

        <td '.$tabOdd.' onclick="tdOption(this);">

            <span class="fSpan">'.$_card["price"].'</span>
             <input type="hidden" id="price" name="title" data-id="'.$_card["id"].'" value="'.$_card["price"].'">
            <input type="text" class="fSel" data-field="price" data-id="'.$_card["id"].'" style="width:150px;display:none">

        </td>



        <td '.$tabOdd.'><button type="button" data-id="'.$_card['id'].'" class="delButton" style="width:100px;font-size: 12px;" onclick="buyProduct();">Buy Product</button></td>';

    echo '</tr>';

}
```

And this is what I used to catch a data from each row.

```
function buyProduct(){
        var c= confirm("Do you want to buy this product?");

        if (c == true) {

            var card = {};

            card['action'] = 'buyCard';

            /*$("form[name]").each(function () {

                var kljuc = $(this).attr("name");

                var vrijednost = $(this).val();

                card[kljuc] = vrijednost;

            });*/
            card['id']=$('.ajdi').val();
            card['title']=$('#title').val();
            card['description']=$('#description').val();
            card['quantity']=$('#quantity').val();
            card['price']=$('#price').val();
            console.log(card['id']);
            $.ajax({

                url: "adapter.php",

                type: "POST",

                dataType: "JSON",

                data: card,

                async: true,

                success: function (data) {

                    if (data > 0) {

                        showSuccess("You added this to cart!");

                    }

                }

            });

            return false;

        }

    }
```

All this does is to take a data(when buy product button is clicked) from first row(which is logical because each line has those ids and classes).

My mentor told me to make a object and take every line data. That didn't help me.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs in a HTML page. The browser will only match the first occurrence as they are stored in a fast-lookup dictionary with only one element per value. You must switch to using classes instead.

Comment: If you want a working example, please provide a sample of the generated output HTML (as saved from the browser). I do not mentally compile PHP any more (it hurts too much) :)

Comment: Thanks for id-removing advice. You gave me a good laugh with that compile critics :D if i understood you well I need to give you a printscreen of the project of web adress. It is on devinfopoint.com/inventory/settings/card.php

Comment: It is run from the same page where table is.. card.php both

Comment: Lots of suggestions for you. Added them all below. Let me know what works or doesn't work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... a few problems and suggestions for you.

- As mentioned you cannot duplicate IDs in a HTML page as that is invalid HTML. Use classes instead. You appear to have that now.
- You have a class of `delButton` on your Buy Product buttons. That can't be a good idea :) I changed it to `class="buyButton"` for the example.
- Don't use inline handlers with jQuery (e.g. `onclick=""`). They separate the event registration from the event code for no reason and make it harder to maintain. I added a delegated event handler that listens for any clicks on any `buyButton` classed elements.

e.g.

```
$('.dayView.dataTable').on('click', '.buyButton', function() {
```

This listens for the `click` event to bubble up to the table. The jQuery selector is used at event time, so this is good for dynamic items too.

- Inside the `buyButton` click handler, you need to know what row you are on. Use `closest`

e.g.

```
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
```

- There is no need to use your object like a dictionary, like `card['id']`. Just access the properties like `card.id`.
- Use scoped jQuery selectors to only search within the row and using the class selectors on the input:

e.g. something like

```
card.id = $('.ajdi', $tr).val();
card.title = $('#title', $tr).val();
card.description = $('.description', $tr).val();
card.quantity = $('.quantity', $tr).val();
card.price = $('.price', $tr).val();
```

So your code becomes something like:

```
$('.dayView.dataTable').on('click', '.buyButton', function() {
  var c = confirm("Do you want to buy this product?");
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  if (c) {
    var card = {};
    card.action = 'buyCard';
    card.id = $('.ajdi').val();
    card.title = $('.title', $tr).val();
    card.description = $('.description', $tr).val();
    card.quantity = $('.quantity', $tr).val();
    card.price = $('.price', $tr).val();
    console.log(card.id);
    $.ajax({

      url: "adapter.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: card,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data > 0) {
          showSuccess("You added this to cart!");
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle (with example stuff I copied):** https://jsfiddle.net/8mbdpcus/1/

Comment: Just corrected an ID selector I missed (`#title`). Just follow the patterns, but not necessarily the exact typing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put some suppliers (suprajzers) to that table!